# I want to access a var in a second view controller in swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Hi here is my code so far

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
        var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)   
        var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        println(latitude)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I would like to access the info in the `locationManager` function in a second view controller showing the `latitude`, `longitude`, `course` and `speed`.  Am a newbie so any help would be great. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move your variables you want to pass to the second VC from local to class-scope:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import MapKit
   import CoreLocation

   class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

       @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!


      var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      var longitude:CLLocationDegrees!
      var latitude:CLLocationDegrees!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       locationManager.delegate = self
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
       locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   }
   ```
2. Create your Target UIViewController with variables to hold the passed values:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import MapKit
   import CoreLocation

   class MyDestinationViewController: UIViewController {
     var longitude:CLLocationDegrees!
     var latitude:CLLocationDegrees!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the `prepareForSegue` method to your viewcontroller from which you want to send the data:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MyDestinationViewController
       destinationVC.latitude = latitude
       destinationVC.longitude = longitude
   }
   ```

If you do not want to use a segue, you can just instanciate the targetViewController and pass the variables, before presenting the VC.

Comment: Thanks very much that has sorted it for me and thanks for the quick reply.